# How to get a list of dbids contained in a layer?

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to access the list of objects or dbids contained with a layer of a 2d model. Ideas? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code to show?

Comment: I have only been able to isolate the layer the object is contained on using viewer.model.getLayersRoot().children which returns to me the layer name, index, and id. I have not been able to find another method which I would be able to pass the layer information in and get the return of its children.

Answer (score 0):

After checking with our dev team, it might be not possible to get a list of dbIds for a layer currently unfortunately. The implementation of the 2D model is not the same as the 3D model.